# How can I get the duration beetwen an empty date timestamp and an other determined?

Tags: php, date, timestamp, delay, duration

I am coding to calculate a duration between an empty timestamp date and an other, non-empty,  Please help me.

I would like to calculate this duration to set a confirmation's code expires when a participant in the forum comes back too late or doesn't come back over 2 days as a maximum delay

This code works fine except when the come back date is empty:

```
$date_participation= strtotime($row['date_participation']);
$date_come_back= strtotime($row['date_come_back']);

$expiration_delay = 2;

$days = $expiration_delay * 86400;
echo "<br> duration in seconds is: " . $date_come_back- 
$date_participation;

if (($date_come_back- $date_participation) >= $days){
    $sql_set_expired = "UPDATE `winners` SET `confirmation_status` = 'expired' WHERE id_recharge_winner ='$i'";
    $set_expired_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_set_expired);
       }

     the `$i` is the participant's row in table winners
```

Comment: What exactly *should* the correct answer for an “empty” timestamp be? It’s not obvious that there *can* be any sensible answer.

Comment: correct answer for an “empty” timestamp should be the current time and like result I would like that the $duration = 86400 or great than 86400 NOT -1546102776

Answer (score 0):

This is how I result my problem whiout worry if there is an Empty date:
I maked my one fuction 
    Difference_between_timestampdate()
than I specify one day like an expiration duration. It works fine, Thanks to those who helped me.

```
 function Difference_between_timestampdate($first_date, $last_date){

 $first_date = strtotime($first_date );
 $last_date = strtotime($last_date);

  $days = $expiration_delay * 82800;

 if(empty($last_date)){
 $duration = time() - $first_date;
  }else{
 $duration = $last_date - $first_date;
 }
 return $duration;
 }


$date_participation = $row['date_participation'];
$date_come_back = $row['date_come_back'];

$expiration_delay = 1; //One day
if ((Difference_between_timestampdate($date_participation, $date_come_back)/82800 ) 
>= $expiration_delay){echo 'Expired duration';}else{echo 'Valid duration';}
```